# How to store datetime in azure cosmosdb from asp.net webapi

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to Azure CosmosDB. I am developing an asp.net webapi to store date of birth of a person in to Azure CosmosDB. I have the datatype as DateTime. What is the best approach to save dateofbirth , in my case, to azure cosmosdb.

When i store as datetime and if dateofbirth is not provided, it stores as:

```
 "dateOfBirth": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
```

Comment: Since `DateTime` is a value type its default value is not `null`. If you want the field to be filled with `null` (or not created at all depending on your serializer settings) you can use `DateTime?` to make it nullable. Same goes for all other valuetypes such as `int`, `double`, `bool`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [**Storing DateTime**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates#storing-datetimes) properties? you just need to store with the type as,

```
public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

You just need to provide a default time in the same format if the values are not available or use the default timestamp